# Volumetric Project Image from Center

Tags: texturing, uv, node-editor, volumetrics, vector-mapping

I've got a volume being generated from an image texture, I just need it to come from the center instead up straight up and down. Here's what I have so far. I tried using UV for the texture coords, but it didn't seem to work with volumetrics.
[image: My current Node tree]

[image: Current Volume]

The red arrows is how it's currently projecting and the green is how I want it to project.

Comment: Try using an environment texture input, just a guess.

Comment: Cody: Is your map Mercator? (Sphere surface -> Full UV rectangle)..  Or do you need to do this to an arbitrary UV Map (seams, islands) ... @ZargulTheWizard That was my guess too... It is really annoying you can't grab `P`, adjust it, and feed that in as the source of the UV calculation... it's all happened before you get to the shader tree.. I think maybe you could use OSL to trace to a real sphere, and pick the UV up from there... there must be a better way. Good question.

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard That worked! I'd like a way to scale the texture down, but I think that may be a different question altogether.

Comment: @RobinBetts I just created a cube and subdivided it three times and added smooth shading. I didn't do anything with the UVs. I think there may be a better way to do it based off of the UV, but the environment texture works for what i need to do with it for now.

Thank you both so much for your help! =)

Comment: @CodyMitchell PTL!